# How to search a word in a html file without any java coding?

Tags: html

I'm doing a project in Java which creates a user manual (html files that are linked together like Windows "Help and support centre") of software. Now once a user manual is created I have only html files remaining. Now I want to search html file that contains specified keyword(Search Engine).How can I do this without Java code??

Comment: why is this tagged with the 'java' keyword when you want to do it without Java?  Do you want to do it Perl?  In C++?  Using grep?

Comment: Sorry my mistake....no i want to do this without java

Comment: Prajakta: You might want to state your preferred choices of language/framework etc.

Comment: I edited the post and removed the 'java' tag.

Answer (score 1):

grep, find, python script, or open any file with a text editor and try edit->search
(on windows use windows search in file)

Comment: The edit -> search part is kinda funny. But should be the first thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your other code is written in java, then it'll be sensible (without knowing your usecase) to use java for searching as well. You might of course use some commandline programs as grep or find - or built in search functionality in a webbrowser, but if the search should be part of a java application anyway, why not go for java and e.g. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org)?

Answer (score 0):

If this 'help' is going to be online than you can embed google search in it (limiting the search results to specified **site:**). Alternatively if you're hosting the pages yourself you can use [htdig](http://www.htdig.org/) for indexing the pages.

However if it's going to offilne you'll be better of by generating a static index page with links to topics. In order to create a more help-system-alike user experience you can hide the contents of the index in the invisible html `DIV` tags and add a JavaScript that takes searched phrase as an input and that unhides the matched words with their links.

Comment: That also came to my mind. But from my experience the search results tend to be incomplete, as the pages have to be indexed and it's not very likely that all pages of a website get indexed (note that indexed != crawled)

Comment: this help is offline for that particular user manual.I m already providing static inedx but now i want to provide some flexibility to user to find particular help page thts why i m doing search engine...I want to design search engine exactly similar to Help n supprt of Windows.....

Comment: @Prajacta B: Edited my answer based on your comment. Maybe a little JavaScript added to the static index would do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but have you looked at [javahelp](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/)? It has indexing and searching built in, and can be used online or offline.